# Presto 313 password-authenticator. properties doesn't work with file

Tags: kubernetes, presto, trino

I'm running presto in K8s and I'm trying to enable file based authentication for the service (using this as a guide https://prestosql.io/docs/current/security/password-file.html). However, as the application is starting up  I get an error saying:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Password authenticator file is not registered

config.properties

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=20GB
query.max-memory-per-node=10GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=10GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://presto-service.eap.svc.cluster.local:8080
http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=8443
http-server.https.keystore.path=/opt/presto-server/etc/presto.jks
http-server.https.keystore.key=*************
```

password-authenticator.properties

```
password-authenticator.name=file
file.password-file=/opt/presto-server/etc/password.db
```

The rest of the config looks perfectly sane so does anybody know what I might have missed here? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Password file authentication was added in version [327](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-327.html), so you need to upgrade it.

> Security Changes
>   Add Password File Authentication. (#797)

You can get the latest version from https://prestosql.io/download.html.
Also, you can join the community Slack. https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: doh! kind of obvious now thinking about it. Thank you very much for the nudge :)

Comment: We can see the past documentation by replacing current with version
https://prestosql.io/docs/313/index.html